# Finding the maximum path sum from root to n-ary leaf in a tree if a negative node restarts the sum from 0

Tags: python, graph, tree

Given a n-ary tree with integer nodes, how to calculate the maximum sum inside a root to leaf path if any negative node resets the sum to 0. 
For eg.,

```
      -3
    /  |   \
  2    4      1
 / \   |\    / | \
1  -1  1 2  2 -1   3
    |    |     | \
    5   -2     4  7
```

Maximum sum inside each leaf to node path:

{-3, 2, 1}  = 3

{-3, 2, -1, 5} = 5

{-3, 4, 1} = 5

{-3, 4, 2, -2} = 6

{-3, 1, 2} = 3

{-3, 1, -1 ,4} = 4

{-3, 1, -1 ,7} = 7

{-3, 1, 3} = 4

The path, {-3, 1, -1 ,7} = 7, will be the maximum sum for the given condition

Comment: I am just trying to understand '{-3, 4, 2, -2} = 6', since the last node is negative, shouldn't the sum equal zero?

Comment: @jdowner The nodes contributing to the maximum sum are only {4,2}. I am listing all the root to leaf paths and then the maximum sum found in each path. No need to add node or nodes that don't improve the maximum sum found already through a path.

Comment: So if, instead of {-3, 1, -1 ,7} , I had {-3, 7, -1 ,1}, the maximum sum would still be 7?

Comment: @jdowner Yes. And if we had {-3 , 7 , -1, 1, 8}, the maximum sum would be 9, the nodes {1,8} contributing towards it.

Answer (score 2):

```
import itertools

class Node(object):
    """Basic class to hold node state"""

    def __init__(self, value, children=None):

        self.value = value
        self.children = list() if children is None else children


def dfs(node):
    """Generator that yields the depth-first paths of the tree"""

    path = list()

    def recurse(n):

        path.append(n)

        if not n.children:
            yield path


        for child in n.children:
            for x in recurse(child):
                yield x

        path.pop()

    for v in recurse(node):
        yield path

# Iterate over the tree from the root node
for path in dfs(root):     

    max_path_value = 0
    # Take the path and split it into groups of positive values
    for valid, nodes in itertools.groupby(path, lambda n: n.value >= 0):
        if valid:
            path_value = sum(n.value for n in nodes)
            if path_value > max_path_value:
                max_path_value = path_value

    path_str = ','.join(map(str, [n.value for n in path]))
    print("{}: {}".format(path_str, max_path_value)
```

Running this on your tree, gives the following output,

```
-3,2,1: 3
-3,2,-1,5: 5
-3,4,1: 5
-3,4,2,-2: 6
-3,1,2: 3
-3,1,-1,4: 4
-3,1,-1,7: 7
-3,1,3: 4
```

Comment: I do not see any code snippet in your code to reset the sum value to 0 when encounter negative leaf value.

Comment: Good catch! I missed that requirements in the original post. I will correct my answer.